# Vue Multiselect not displaying

Tags: laravel, vue.js, multi-select, vuejs2

I am trying to use Vue Multiselect V2 in my Laravel 5.3 project. I am using this example, http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/#sub-single-select

I have the following setup, in my **app.js** file:

```
Vue.component('multiselect', require('./components/Multiselect.vue'));

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

In the **Multiselect.vue** file

```
<script>
  import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

  export default {
    components: {
      Multiselect
    },
    data () {
      return {
        value: '',
        options: ['Select option', 'options', 'selected', 'mulitple', 'label', 'searchable', 'clearOnSelect', 'hideSelected', 'maxHeight', 'allowEmpty', 'showLabels', 'onChange', 'touched']
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And I am calling it in the **blade** as below:

```
<div id="app">
  <label class="typo__label">Single select</label>
  <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" :searchable="false" :close-on-select="false" :show-labels="false" placeholder="Pick a value"></multiselect>
  <pre class="language-json"><code>@{{ value  }}</code></pre>
</div>
```

This is how it displays in the **DOM**

```
<div id="app">
  <label class="typo__label">Single select</label>
  <!---->
  <pre class="language-json"><code></code></pre>
</div>
```

Currently the dropdown does not display, and I don't see any errors in the console. I would have expected to add a template in somewhere but I couldn't find any mention of that in the Vue Multiselect docs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For anyone having these issues, do not follow the examples on the official documentation. They do not work, rather use this from their Github page. https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect/tree/2.0#install--basic-usage

**Basic example**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <multiselect
      v-model="selected"
      :options="options">
    </multiselect>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
  export default {
    components: { Multiselect },
    data () {
      return {
        selected: null,
        options: ['list', 'of', 'options']
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
```

Comment: The last bit `<style>` is crucial. Sometimes when you don't include it it will work locally, but drop on build - then you know you have to add it separately to the problematic component.

Comment: @ClintonGreen for the options in the data(), how would I pass through an array of objects and only display the object.titles ??? RIght now I pass an array from my props and it passes the entire json object, Should I loop through using a method then pass this.myMethod to the options: this.myMethod in data?

Comment: @jeand'arme for the options in the data(), how would I pass through an array of objects and only display the object.titles ??? RIght now I pass an array from my props and it passes the entire json object, Should I loop through using a method then pass this.myMethod to the options: this.myMethod in data?

Answer (score 0):

For updating the array from vue multiselect use **@select** and **@remove** events

```
Example: <multiselect  @select="selectionChange" @remove="removeElement"> </multiselect>

Into methods add the next functions

methods: {
    removeElement() {
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
    selectionChange() {
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
}

this.$forceUpdate(); will update the state.
```